# If an optimization problem is NP-hard under the L1-metric, then what can we say about the problem under the L2-metric?

Tags: algorithm, np-hard

I have come across a few classic problems such as the k-means and k-median problems are being studied under various metrics for inapproximability results. I have a general (perhaps silly) question. If an optimization problem is NP-hard under the L1-metric, then what can we say about the problem under the L2-metric?. Similarly, if we know that an optimization problem is APX-hard under the L1-metric, then what can we say about the APX-hardness of the problem under the L2-metric?. Can you please clarify me or provide me a reference/link?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that we can say anything in general. It very probably depends on both the problem and the metric used.

Comment: I would gess the same as @m.raynal

Comment: @m.raynal and sascha Thank you for your answers.